# Total Enumeration with Groupings

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, enumerable

The following view establishes a grid of grouped items.  The goal is to give the enumerated item **overall** not by grouping

```
<% biz.documents.in_groups_of(5).each do |documents| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <% documents.each_with_index do |document, index| %>
      <div class="small-2 columns text-center">
        <% if document %>
          <i>Item <%= index + 1 %></i>
```

Practically: given groupings of 5, if there are 7 items, the output ends-up being

```
index 1 index 2 index 3 index 4 index 5  
index 1 index 2
```

Is there a way to get an enum of each grouping so that it can multiply itself by the grouping factor and be added to the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` in your grouped, outer loop as well. Try this:

```
<% biz.documents.in_groups_of(5).each_with_index do |documents, group_index| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <% documents.each_with_index do |document, index| %>
      <div class="small-2 columns text-center">
        <% if document %>
          <i>Item <%= (group_index * 5) + index + 1 %></i>
```

It should produce the result you are looking for.

Comment: ahhh!  It's the `|documents, group_index|` which is the kicker! huzzah!